# OSX Mavericks - Set up Apache with subdomains

Tags: php, macos, apache, subdomain

I have successfully set up a local server running PHP on my Mac, but I am having trouble setting up extra local sites as subdomains (i.e. site2.localhost)

Here's what I have so far:

hosts file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       site2.localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/user/Sites/site2"
    ServerName site2.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and I've uncommented the following line in the httpd.conf file:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I'm not sure what else I need to add or where I need to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, seems as if I needed to look a little harder... It was in fact set up correctly, but for some reason when I typed site2.localhost into the browser it was defaulting to https.

By manually typing in http://site2.localhost it works fine.